# Verificar se o span da mesma coluna possui a mesma classe com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript

Tenho nove span, 3 em cada row, quando os 3 spans da mesma row possuem determinada classe eu exibo uma mensagem, gostaria de saber como fazer a mesma lógica se os span da mesma coluna tiverem a mesma classe.

```
<body>
<h1 class="text-center">Teste Bingo</h1>
<div class="num text-center">
    <p id="numSorteio"></p>
</div>
<div class="sorteio col-12 text-center">
    <a href="#" id="bt-gerar" class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-randow" >sorteio</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col-sm" value="3"><span  class="span-bingo n3">3</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="8"><span class="span-bingo n8">8</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="10"><span class="span-bingo n10">10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-sm" value="14"><span class="span-bingo n14">14</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="20"><span class="span-bingo n20">20</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="28"><span class="span-bingo n28">28</span></div>
        </div>
    <div class="row row3">
            <div class="col-sm" value="32"><span class="span-bingo n32">32</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm" value="40"><span class="span-bingo n40">40</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm" value="49"><span class="span-bingo n49">49</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var sorteio = document.querySelector('p#numSorteio')
var sortNum = sorteio.innerHTML
var numAleatorio
 document.getElementById("bt-gerar").onclick = gerarAleatorio = () =>{
    numAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
    sorteio.innerHTML = numAleatorio
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('span'), i;
    var div = document.querySelector('span')

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
      if(divs[i].innerText == numAleatorio){
        divs[i].classList.remove("span-bingo")
        divs[i].classList.add("numeroSorteado")

        }
      }
        // busca as rows
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.container .row');

    for(var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++){
       if(rows[x].querySelectorAll(".numeroSorteado").length == 3){
          // console.log("BINGO na linha "+ (x+1));
          sorteio.innerHTML = 'BINGO'
          break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: uma duvida: se usa `bootstrap`, também não usar `jquery`?

Comment: é só pra nível de conhecimento mesmo. Estou começando estudar javascript e gostaria de praticar bastante com ele puro, antes de partir para jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma que encontrei é com a ajuda de uma array, onde você irá armazenar o índice da coluna dentro da row onde foi encontrado um elemento com a classe `.numeroSorteado`.

Como são 3 colunas, se encontrar na primeira coluna, a array ficará:

```
cols = [0] // o "0" representa a 1ª coluna
```

No próximo sorteio, se achar na última coluna (índice 2), a array passará a ser:

```
cols = [0,2]
```

Com essa lógica, a cada número sorteado, você adiciona na array o índice da coluna e em seguida conta quantos elementos do mesmo valor a array possui. Se retornar 3, significa que 3 números da mesma coluna foram sorteados. Por exemplo:

```
        ↓     ↓ ↓
cols = [0,2,1,0,0] // significa que 3 números a 1ª coluna possuem a classe .numeroSorteado
```

Você vai criar uma array vazia seguida de um `for` que irá percorrer cada row (aproveitando a coleção em `var rows`). Dentro desse `for` irá fazer outro `for` para percorrer cada `span` e verificar se a span possui a classe `.numeroSorteado`. Se encontrar, insere na array o valor da variável do `for` (que representa o índice da span dentro da div). Em seguida outro `for` percorrendo a array para contar quantos itens possui o valor da variável do `for`. Se o valor for 3, acaba ali com `break;`, ou seja, houve o Bingo por coluna.

Veja no código o trecho adicionado abaixo do comentário `// verificar colunas` que você verá o que descrevi acima:

```js
var sorteio = document.querySelector('p#numSorteio')
var sortNum = sorteio.innerHTML
var numAleatorio
 document.getElementById("bt-gerar").onclick = gerarAleatorio = () =>{
    numAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
    sorteio.innerHTML = numAleatorio
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('span'), i;
    var div = document.querySelector('span')

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
      if(divs[i].innerText == numAleatorio){
        divs[i].classList.remove("span-bingo")
        divs[i].classList.add("numeroSorteado")

        }
      }
        // busca as rows
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.container .row');


   // verificar colunas
    var cols = []
    for(var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++){
       
       var spans = rows[x].querySelectorAll('span');
       
       for(var y = 0; y < spans.length; y++){
          var conta = 0;
          
          if(~spans[y].className.indexOf("numeroSorteado")){
             cols.push(y);
             
             for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++){
                if(cols[i] == y) conta++;
             }
             
             if(conta == 3){
                console.log("BINGO na coluna "+ (y+1));
                break;
             }
             
          }

       }
       
       // verificar linhas
       if(rows[x].querySelectorAll(".numeroSorteado").length == 3){
          console.log("BINGO na linha "+ (x+1));
          sorteio.innerHTML = 'BINGO'
          break;
       }
    }
 }
```

```css
.numeroSorteado{
   color: white;
   background: blue;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1 class="text-center">Teste Bingo</h1>
<div class="num text-center">
    <p id="numSorteio"></p>
</div>
<div class="sorteio col-12 text-center">
    <a href="#" id="bt-gerar" class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-randow" >sorteio</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col-sm" value="3"><span  class="span-bingo n3">3</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="8"><span class="span-bingo n8">8</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="10"><span class="span-bingo n10">10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-sm" value="14"><span class="span-bingo n14">14</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="20"><span class="span-bingo n20">20</span></div>
        <div class="col-sm" value="28"><span class="span-bingo n28">28</span></div>
        </div>
    <div class="row row3">
            <div class="col-sm" value="32"><span class="span-bingo n32">32</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm" value="40"><span class="span-bingo n40">40</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm" value="49"><span class="span-bingo n49">49</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```